# .find() returning nothing even when data exists

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've a mongo database with 3 collections for 3 different kind of users as User,Partner,Admin. Whenever a new user of any type signup I'm searching all three collections to check if username and email exist already. I'm trying to achieve this by calling a function as:

```
function checkAttribute(attr,val,callback){
    User.find({attr: val},function(err,user){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            if(user.length === 0){
                    Partner.find({attr: val},function(err,partner){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }else{
                        if(partner.length === 0){
                            Admin.find({attr: val},function(err,admin){
                                if(err){
                                    console.log(err);
                                }else{
                                    if(admin.length === 0){
                                        return callback(null,true);
                                    }else{
                                        return callback(null,false);
                                    } 
                                }
                            });
                        }else{
                            return callback(null,false);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }else{
                return callback(null,false);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Calling function line:

```
checkAttribute("username",newUser.username,function(error,response){
.......
});
```

But this is not working as it returns true always even when users with passed username/email exists already. I am unable to find the problem. Any one knows why this is happening? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Trying using count() query

Comment: Why you are returning callback with return callback(null,false)? even though you have find user.

Comment: @chirag.sweng because if a user with given username or email is found then i cant add new user with same value so returning false depicts I cant add the registered user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are passing in the attribute as a variable in the function parameters, the query document 
`{ attr: val }` is an object with the key "attr", not the dynamic attribute you pass in.

To fix this, you need to use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) in your query object as

```
{ [attr]: val }
```

Also, the function can use async/await pattern to be more readable and for the purpose of finding if a document exist [`findOne`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) does the job so
well as it returns a document if it exists and null otherwise.

So your function can be refactored as

```
async function checkAttribute(attr, val, callback) {
    try {
        const query = { [attr]: val }
        const user = await User.findOne(query).exec()
        const partner = await Partner.findOne(query).exec()
        const admin = await Admin.findOne(query).exec()

        const found = (user || partner || admin) ? true: false
        return callback(null, found)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return callback(err, null)
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`attr:` in your queries will search for a db field called `attr`. If you want to use the function parameter `attr`, use `[attr]:` as the key.

#### Example:

```
 attr = 'username'
 User.find({ [attr]: val }, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
 })
```

This is a feature available since ES6 so should work fine. See the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) for more info